# Firefox error console shows errors from unrelated other site

Tags: firefox

Whenever I load my page into Firefox the Error Console shows:

[image]

I'm not purposely loading anything from Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange and the text "stackexchange" doesn't show up anywhere in my source.  Does anyone know what these errors are?

Comment: If you're going to recommend that the question be closed because it's been asked before, how about providing a link to that question and answer.  I don't see it in "Questions that may have your answer."

Comment: The stackoverflow tag is for problems in YOUR programs, not the stack exchange network.  The close votes against your question currently are to have it moved to http://meta.stackoverflow.com (under the assumption that your question is support related).  If you don't think that's correct then you may want to consider expanding your question (is the issue specific to your page, not general web browsing after using stackexchange, is it for all pages on your site or just one, what's unique if anything about that page etc).

Comment: I don't know if the problem is my program or not. But If I'll get an answer at meta.stackoverflow.com it's fine with me to move it.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the (old) Firefox error console, which shows messages from all web pages you've got open, from the browser's own code, and from add-ons.

To see what's happening to *your* website only, use [the web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) instead. (Hit Control+Shift+K or Command+Option+K.)